Set Content-Security-Policy header for @google/model-viewer
I want to use the @google/model-viewer to display 3D models, but my CSP header blocks the inline styles that the viewer creates. Is there a way to enable the viewer using nonce or other means?
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.min.js"></script>

style_src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'

solves it but I would like to avoid it.

What specific error messages are you getting without unsafe-inline?

Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' https://cdn.jsdelivr.net https://fonts.googleapis.com https://www.gstatic.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-yhlpZVZMy2vXExwTGihUWVSrOxyhMuvj+Ygg7pyBWek='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. template.js:374

So the message says you should be able to either use a nonce, or a hash, instead. Which of those have you tried? Which problem did you run into?

Please correct me if I'm wrong. I can use nonce when I render html on the backend, add it to the inline scripts and styles. However, content of this module is only loaded from the frontend. Hash is used for static content. Since the content is loaded from a remote source and I don't have access to the content, the hash will be bad when the authors change the content. Is there any possibility to add a nonce attribute to the script tag so that after the components of the loaded module use this nonce? Thanks.

"the hash will be bad when the authors change the content" - the script source you are using there, automatically redirects me to https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer@4.0.0/dist/model-viewer.min.js, with the specific version number 4.0.0 in the URL. If you explicitly embed that version to begin with, then you should not have to worry about any changes to the source code. If the developers had anything to add or change, they would publish a new version. The whole internet pretty much relies on versioned scripts staying as they are.

Yes, it makes sense. I've specified the version and entered the hash in the CSP header and it works. Thank you for your help.

@C3roe Could you please post it as an answer so I can mark it as the accepted solution?

According to the message you got, you should be able to either use a nonce, or a hash, instead of 'unsafe-inline'.
If the dynamic generation of a nonce is not an option in your setup, then the hash variant is the way to go.
And by switching from the current embed URL, which basically translates to "give me the newest version", to a URL that explicitly loads a specific version, you should not have to worry about changes to that script source either - that's what it was "versioned" for, so that developers using it can rely on it staying the same. If the providers of this script resource need to make any updates or changes, they would release a new version.
